# Ignore footnotes when exporting org texts to html

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to export org texts to HTML. This is easy if I use `org-export-string-as`. The problem is, the org texts may contain unreferenced footnotes, I want the export function to ignore the footnotes. Here is my code:

```lisp
(let ((org-text (concat "* Header\n" "Text[fn:1]."))
      (my-backend (org-export-create-backend
                   :parent 'html
                   :transcoders '((footnote-reference . ignore)))))
  (org-export-string-as org-text my-backend t nil))
```

As you can see, I set the transcoder of `footnote-reference` to `ignore`, but it doesn't work. I still got an error when running the above code:

```
Definition not found for footnote 1
```

Why? What should I do?

Comment: Did you try to set `org-export-with-footnotes` to `nil`? Or in the buffer, `#+OPTIONS: f:nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `org-export-with-footnotes` to `nil` seems to work fine:

```el
(let ((org-text (concat "* Header\n" "Text[fn:1]."))
      (my-backend (org-export-create-backend
                   :parent 'html
                   ;;:transcoders '((footnote-reference . ignore))
                   ))
      (org-export-with-footnotes nil))
  (org-export-string-as org-text my-backend t nil))
```

It produces:

```html
"<div id=\"table-of-contents\" role=\"doc-toc\">
<h2>Table of Contents</h2>
<div id=\"text-table-of-contents\" role=\"doc-toc\">
<ul>
<li><a href=\"#org27ffc60\">1. Header</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id=\"outline-container-org27ffc60\" class=\"outline-2\">
<h2 id=\"org27ffc60\"><span class=\"section-number-2\">1.</span> Header</h2>
<div class=\"outline-text-2\" id=\"text-1\">
<p>
Text.</p>
</div>
</div>
"
```

Of course, you don't need `my-backend` any longer, but I left that in just in case you have other things up your sleeve :-)

Comment: It works, thanks!